# Given $2x+y=180$ is true for a triangle, which quantity is bigger out of 4 choices?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Ok so I have the following question:

[image]

Each angle in ∆QRS has a degree measurement of either x or y and the angles are expressed by the equation 2x + y = 180

Quantity A

The perimeter of $\triangle QRS$

Quantity B

17

Which of the following statements are true?

A) Quantity A is greater.
B) Quantity B is greater.
C) The two quantities are equal.
D) The relationship cannot be determined from the information given.

My initial try was that as the angles are 2x+y=180 the triangle is isosceles and  RS must be $7$, thus the perimeter of $\triangle QRS$ is $7+7+4 = 18 > 17$ and the correct answer is A.

Apparently, the **correct answer** is D, as someone noted that QS can also be $4$, so $7+4+4=15 < 17$, so it can't be determined. Can anyone explain why is that? Is it because QS is not fixed, so it could also take $4$ as value?

[image]

Also isn't the graph misleading in order to make you think only of the first choice?   Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a GRE question. The figures are never drawn to scale unless specifically stated. And so in this case, you cannot assign angles $x$ and $y$ on your own unless additional information is given.

Comment: Oh I know they are not, I evaluated the triangle as isosceles based on the $2x+y=180 $ equation. My mind got way too attached to the photo however and made me think the only correct way is if $QS = 8$.

Comment: So I assume you understand why D is the correct answer then?

Comment: Yeah, I do now, I just was not so sure if the 2nd graph of QS=4 line was correct and if that was why 4 was suggested as the second possible value. I get it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your reasonement is correct. In fact, without further informations we can't determine the angle adiacent to the base. So there are two different possibilities for the perimetre:
$$P=7+7+4=18>17$$
Or:
$$4+4+7=15<17$$
So the correct answer is $D$ because we don't have much more informations.

Comment: @george.zrs: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?